# PS shows process with 0% cpu and 0% memory usage

Tags: linux, ubuntu

why those processes appear if they are not consuming any cpu or memory.
Is there any way to show only process that are really consuming memory or cpu?

Comment: If you are interested in performance, `htop` will let you sort by CPU usage or memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

1. Processes with 0% CPU/RAM usage are kernel threads.
2. You can always run `top` or `htop` and use P T M keys to sort by CPU usage, CPU time and memory usage.
3. Pressing 0 in `top` will hide zeros on the screen which makes it look less cluttered.
4. To hide kernel threads from `ps` output please refer to [Is there any way to hide kernel threads from ps command results?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258448/is-there-any-way-to-hide-kernel-threads-from-ps-command-results)